# How to change the hibernate entity cache configuration at run time

Tags: hibernate, ehcache

I am using annotation based configuration to configure the cache strategy for all hibernate entities like as below

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EMP")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class EMPLOYEE extends AbstractEntity {
```

We have common project to maintain all hibernate entity clasess. we will building a jar and using it in different applications. We are using this entity jar in two applications. I have to use different caching strategies for two applications.
For application1 , i have to use @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
and for application 2, i have to use @Cache(usage =  CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY).

So i would like to change these configuration settings dynamically at run time for application2.

Appreciated , if anyone can suggest the approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to change the caching policy for a class run-time. You need just to have a separate class with constants like this:

```
public abstract class Settings {
   public static final CacheConcurrencyStrategy CACHE_STRATEGY;

   static {
      // initialize the field, e.g. based on a value from a properties file
   }
}

then 

@Entity
@Table(name = "EMP")
@Cache(usage = Settings.CACHE_STRATEGY)
public class EMPLOYEE extends AbstractEntity {...}
```

Then just have two different files with properties for different applications.

P.S. it doesn't have to be a separate class with the constant. It just an example how things can be organized better, from my point of view.